# How to track when a relation value of a record has changed using onBeforeSave event?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a one to many relationship between user and userTitle where the title of the user is accessed using the relation like this: `user.Title;` 
Comparing the new and old records is not working because although the title of the user has definitely changed `record.Title._key is in fact equal to oldRecord.Title._key` inside onBeforeSave user model. However checking the foreign key `record.title_fk and oldRecord.title_fk` produces an expected result ( that is they are different ).

What to do if I want to track history of records?

Comment: There is a feature request for this here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62655076. Unfortunately this was left out of App Maker or its is a bug, not sure which.

Comment: Ya I saw that. That is really unfortunate!!
The question is thought, why was is it let out? It's such an important feature. Why else is it there record and oldRecord if its not going to be working as expected!